# Can't I call rand() multy times in a line?

Tags: c++, random

```
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        Vertex v;
        v.pos = (glm::vec3)((GLfloat)(rand() % 100) / 50 - 1, (GLfloat)(rand() % 100) / 50 - 1, (GLfloat)(rand() % 100) / 50 - 1);
        v.col = (glm::vec3)((GLfloat)(rand() % 100) / 100, (GLfloat)(rand() % 100) / 100, (GLfloat)(rand() % 100) / 100);
        tri4.objData.vertices.push_back(v);
        std::cout << tri4.objData.vertices.at(i).pos.x <<"\t" <<i4.objData.vertices.at(i).pos.y<<"\t"<< tri4.objData.vertices.at(i).pos.z << "\n\n";
        std::cout << tri4.objData.vertices.at(i).col.x << "\t" << tri4.objData.vertices.at(i).col.y << "\t" << tri4.objData.vertices.at(i).col.z << "\n\n";

        tri4.objData.indices.push_back(i);
        std::cout << tri4.objData.indices.at(i) << '\n';
    }
```

this is my GL codes
in tihis case, pos.x and pos.y are same..
those three rand()s are return same at 'v.pos=' line or 'v.col=' line..
I did't use srand(time) or something.
does rand()s return same values on one line?
or vec3 has problem with it?

Comment: 1. `rand()` is generally not a very good pseudo-random number generator. 2. Using `%` to generate random numbers in a particular range makes it *even worse* by adding bias.

Comment: @jamesdlin: that's true if you're doing crypto and such, not so important for games or things like that :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Well, depends on the game.  You'd want something better for, say, a poker game, but yeah, for graphics calculations, it's not a big deal.  My point was that given the problems, it might not be *too* surprising if it happened to generate the same numbers.

Comment: I found my mistake. (glm::vec3) doesn't work right. it returns last value 3 times.

Comment: The reason it isn't working for you is that you are using `v.pos = (glm::vec3)(...)` which is casting the stuff denoted by `...` into a vec3.  But the `...` is three comma separated GLfloat values.  The comma operator discards the first two and the third one is casted into a vec3 using the single argument constructor and that's why there is only one value.  You don't want a cast - you want the three argument constructor - so call `v.pos = glm::vec3(...)` without the parenthesis.  Here is an example: https://onlinegdb.com/B16Nt5FBD

Comment: thx Jerry Jeremiah. that was the problem. also thx to all the other guys.

Comment: Here is maybe a better example that shows the single argument constructor vs the three argument constructor: https://onlinegdb.com/HJ6OacKHv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it isn't working for you is that you are using

```
v.pos = (glm::vec3)(...)
```

which is casting the stuff denoted by `...` into a vec3.

But the `...` is three comma separated GLfloat values. The comma operator discards the first two and the third one is casted into a vec3 using the single argument constructor and that's why there is only one value.

You don't want a cast - you want the three argument constructor - so go without the parenthesis:

```
v.pos = glm::vec3(...)
```

Here is a comparison between the cast and what you were really trying to do:

```
#include <iostream>

struct vec3 {
    int x, y, z;
    vec3(int v) : x(v), y(v), z(v) { std:: cout << "vec3(int v)\n"; }
    vec3(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) { std:: cout << "vec3(int x,int y,int z)\n"; }
};

int main() {
    vec3 pos = (vec3)(1,2,3); // calls vec3(3)
    vec3 col = vec3(1,2,3);   // calls vec3(1,2,3)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each invocation of the function is considered a separate call, with a (most likely) different result.

You can verify this with *any* function, such as with:

```
#include <iostream>

int getVal() {
    static int val = 0;
    return ++val;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << getVal() * getVal() * getVal() << '\n';
}
```

This will give you `1 * 2 * 3`, or `6`.

Comment: It's worth noting that the *order* of the calls isn't guaranteed.  But for your example and the OP's question that wouldn't matter.